# Get page title & URL and echo in HTML

Tags: php

I am attempting to dynamically grab a page's title and URL and `echo` into HTML. Here's what I have:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="mailto:?Subject=<?php echo $page_title?>&body=<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" class="email" title="Email">Email</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The URL successfully `echos`, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way? And I can not figure out how to print the page's title via `<?php echo $page_title?>`?

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no global PHP variable which corresponds to the page `<title>`. Unless you earlier used the `$page_title` variable to specify the `<title>`...

```
<?php $page_title = "My Page Title"; ?>
<title><?php echo $page_title ?></title>
```

...`<?php echo $page_title?>` wont' do anything special.

If you did use the `$page_title` variable in this way, you might need to encode the data. It should be both URI encoded and HTML encoded - in that order.

```
<a href="mailto:?Subject=<?php echo htmlentities(urlencode($page_title)); ?>" class="email" title="Email">Email</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$page_title` is just a variable. If you define it, then it will echo. You might want to have `<title><?php echo $page_title?></title>` in your `<head>`, again assuming you actually define that variable.

PHP isn't some magical force, it is a programming language and as such it does what you tell it to do.